# Cipher class from javax.crypto package not working as expected using the DES algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, des

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] pText) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(key)); // Outputs: 3FBB589A6A941D01
    System.out.println( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(pText)); // Outputs: 92F3BD61F852727E
    Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey blah = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "DES");

    ciph.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  blah);
    byte[] test = ciph.doFinal(pText); 
    System.out.println( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(test)); // Outputs: 4799F8A1C0A427E17E2B19DD22064444

    return test;
}
```

A couple of things I as unsure on:

1. I padded the key with 01, that is why the output on the first line ends with 01. I tried padding it with 0s but that did not work either. And the required length is 8 bytes. So not sure if I did that right.
2. I am not completely sure what offset means in the SecretKey constructor(2nd argument). I am assuming it should be 0.
3. My main question is why is test(the cipherText) 16 bytes? According to http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ernet.in/~sourav/DES.pdf page 13 it should be only 8 bytes.

I also know my code is not working because I know what the final encrypted output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the mode and padding for the cipher in the call to `getInstance()`, so the provider will choose default parameters. Your provider is defaulting to "PKCS5Padding", so it add 8 bytes with a value of 0x08 to your plain text before performing the DES encryption.

To avoid platform-dependent behavior, it's very important to specify a complete transformation when creating a `Cipher` instance: algorithm, mode, and padding. If you don't want padding, say so:

```
Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
SecretKey blah = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");
```

Why did you pad your key? Why wasn't your key 8 bytes long to start? If the first 7 bytes are intended to be used as the actual key, and lack parity bits, you can't just slap a byte on the end; you need to expand the key to eight bytes, appending one parity bit to each 7-bit chunk.

If you use the parity-adjusted key, `3EDCD613A754513B`, and no padding, the cipher text is `C094C47D7F89E219`. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was expecting.